# Variables in .npmrc are not loaded into process.env.npm_config_*

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, environment-variables

I have a node js script that reads some token variables in a `/home/myname/myproject/.npmrc` file like this:

```
MY_TOKEN_A=abc
```

I run the script by `cd /home/myname/myproject && npm run mytask`

and the script can read the variable like this:

```js
const THE_TOKEN_A = process.env.npm_config_MY_TOKEN_A;
```

It worked perfectly but today it suddenly fails. The `THE_TOKEN_A` becomes `undefiend`. I tried `cd /home/myname/myproject && npm config list` it shows:

```
; "project" config from /home/myname/myproject/.npmrc

MY_TOKEN_A = "abc"
```

which means the npm has no problem to get the config from the `.npmrc` in the same directory, but why it doesn't put the config into `process.env` anymore?

The enviroment is npm/7.6.1 node/v15.11.0 linux x64.

Comment: I'd guess that's related to https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md - did you upgrade to NPM 7 recently?

Comment: Yes, the NPM was upgraded by my admin. That seems the answer, thank you.